# Tomcat migration self signed certificate not send via Rest client

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, spring-security

We have two `war` applications **working during development on single tomcat.**

The first war is front server that serves JSP and other html content and backend server that is supposed to process all data via requests from browser through front server that uses `JBoss ReastEasy` to connect to backend REST endpoints.

During migration from `Tomcat-7.0.57` to `Tomcat-9.0.6` I encountered a problem with certificate that is not send **from front server to backend server.**

More precisly I copied all crucial folders with `.JKS`, configuration files, certificate and modified configuration to comply with new `SSLHostConfig` tag in tomcat 9.

Unfortunately, we are experiencing problem with requests from fron-server to back-end, it looks like the certificate is not send in requests, so backend server `Spring Security` throws AccessDeniedException, since it creates an annonymous session.

Here is spring security from backend server:

```
2018-03-28 15:46:58,607 [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession:174  - No HttpSession currently exists
2018-03-28 15:46:58,607 [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext:116  - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2018-03-28 15:46:58,624 [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter:325  - /service/admin/users/filteredSearch at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-03-28 15:46:58,655 [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter:325  - /service/admin/users/filteredSearch at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'X509AuthenticationFilter'
2018-03-28 15:46:58,656 [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.p.x.X509AuthenticationFilter.doFilter:113  - Checking secure context token: null
2018-03-28 15:46:58,657 [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.p.x.X509AuthenticationFilter.extractClientCertificate:57  - No client certificate found in request.
2018-03-28 15:46:58,658 [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.p.x.X509AuthenticationFilter.extractClientCertificate:57  - No client certificate found in request.
2018-03-28 15:46:58,658 [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.p.x.X509AuthenticationFilter.doAuthenticate:169  - No pre-authenticated principal found in request
2018-03-28 15:46:58,679 [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired:348  - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2018-03-28 15:46:58,723 [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException:173  - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Update with server.xml SSL connector:

```
  <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
               compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
               compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/json,text/javascript,text/css,text/plain,application/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/xml,application/xml+xhtml,application/json" 
               useSendfile="false" URIEncoding="UTF-8">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/server.jks" certificateKeystorePassword="certKeyPass" type="RSA" truststoreFile="${catalina.home}/conf/server.jks" truststorePassword="passwordHere" certificateKeyAlias="certAlias" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

Code for Rest Client

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    if (sslDebug) {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "SSL:handshake");
    }

final File file = new File(sslKeystoreFilepath);
    final FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(is, sslKeystorePassword.toCharArray());

    trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    final PortalKeyManager manager = new PortalKeyManager(keyStore, serverKeyPassword, endpointAlias, serverAlias);
    sslContext.init(new KeyManager[] { manager }, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
    manager.getCertificateChain(serverAlias)[0].getSubjectDN().getName();

    builder = new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(maxTotal)
            .hostnameVerification(HostnameVerificationPolicy.ANY)
            .trustStore(keyStore)
            .socketTimeout(soTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .maxPooledPerRoute(defaultMaxPerRoute)
            .connectionCheckoutTimeout(connectionTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .connectionTTL(connectionTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .establishConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .sslContext(sslContext);
}
```

Comment: You didn't configure `clientAuth` or `certificateVerification`, hence the client doesn't send a client certificate.

Comment: @dur I've added configuration for RestClient

Comment: Did you try `certificateVerification="required"`?

Comment: @dur Yes, I've added it exactly as you wrote. Apologize, for earlier mistake, it was `certificateVerification="required"` from the beginning, not `clientAuth`